# Broken python dependencies after trying to re-install

Tags: 18.04, dpkg, dependencies, python3

I had several installations of python on my ubuntu 18.04 system and tried to uninstall all necessary ones and just properly reinstall python3.6

So i deleted all folders that were listed under `whereis python`, probably that was a bad idea.

Now if I run `sudo apt-get install python3.6` it returns

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
python3.6 is already the newest version (3.6.5-3).
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 4 not upgraded.
4 not fully installed or removed.
After this operation, 0 B of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] y
Setting up python3.6-minimal (3.6.5-3) ...
Could not find platform independent libraries <prefix>
Consider setting $PYTHONHOME to <prefix>[:<exec_prefix>]
Fatal Python error: Py_Initialize: Unable to get the locale encoding
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'encodings'

Current thread 0x00007f814f83c740 (most recent call first):
Aborted
dpkg: error processing package python3.6-minimal (--configure):
 installed python3.6-minimal package post-installation script subprocess returned error exit status 134
Setting up python-minimal (2.7.15~rc1-1) ...
/var/lib/dpkg/info/python-minimal.postinst: 4: /var/lib/dpkg/info/python-minimal.postinst: python2.7: not found
dpkg: error processing package python-minimal (--configure):
 installed python-minimal package post-installation script subprocess returned error exit status 127
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of python3.6:
 python3.6 depends on python3.6-minimal (= 3.6.5-3); however:
  Package python3.6-minimal is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package python3.6 (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of python3.6-dev:
 python3.6-dev depends on python3.6 (= 3.6.5-3); however:
  Package python3.6 is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package python3.6-dev (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
Errors were encountered while processing:
 python3.6-minimal
 python-minimal
 python3.6
 python3.6-dev
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

I then tried to update the minimal package with `sudo apt-get install -f --reinstall python3.6-minimal` but that returns

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 1 reinstalled, 0 to remove and 4 not upgraded.
4 not fully installed or removed.
After this operation, 0 B of additional disk space will be used.
E: Internal Error, No file name for python3.6-minimal:amd64
```

I'm not really an experienced linux user, so I'm quite stuck here. Does someone have an idea how I can fix my python installation?

Comment: Anyone got an idea?

Comment: Would still be really happy if I could fix this without a complete Ubuntu re-install

Comment: use `apt-get purge --remove <package> && apt autoremove && apt autoclean` and install again your python

Comment: and `<package>` would be what? Sorry I'm not really a Linux user...

Comment: use <package> as python3.6

Comment: `purge` is failing with `Could not find platform independent libraries <prefix> Could not find platform dependent libraries <exec_prefix> Consider setting $PYTHONHOME to <prefix>[:<exec_prefix>]
Fatal Python error: Py_Initialize: Unable to get local encoding ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'encodings'`
So same output as I listed in my question for `sudo apt-get install pyhton3.6`

Comment: you still have 4 not upgrade, type `apt-get update && apt-get upgrade && dpkg --configure -a && sudo dpkg-configure python3.6`

Comment: Unfortunately that doesn't help. What seems strange to me is when I do `apt-get install python3.6-minimal` it somehow refers to python2.7.
What does that `Could not find platform dependent/independent libraries` message mean? Is my Python not properly deleted or have I deleted files I should have not?

Comment: the output said "Errors were encountered while processing:
 python3.6-minimal
 python-minimal
 python3.6
 python3.6-dev" ,try to type `apt-get install --fix-broken`

Comment: Gives the same output... :(
Additionally it says that `dpkg: error processing package python3.6 (--configure): dependency problems - leaving unconfigured` and the same for `python3.6-dev`

Comment: you still encountered while processing python-minimal, try to `apt-get purge python* && apt-get autoclean && apt-get install python*` sir

Comment: Still the same messages. So I guess the only option that's left is to re-install the whole Linux?

Comment: abu-ahmed al-khatiri, can you create an answer out of your comments? I got it fixed... not sure why exactly it didn't work the first time.

Comment: If anyone has a similar "python is broken or not fully installed" error, try checking the symlinks. In my case, my `/usr/bin/python3` symlink was incorrectly set (I think because I was messing with pyenv or something) and so I had to relink it to `/usr/bin/python3.9`, the system python version for Ubuntu 21.04. After that, it was still not configured correctly, so I ran `sudo apt install --reinstall python3.9` and then everything clicked back in place.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

> dpkg: error processing package python3.6-minimal (--configure):
>   dpkg: error processing package python3.6 (--configure):
>   dpkg: error processing package python3.6-dev (--configure):

You have 3 dpkg package error to need reconfigure, one thing to do that follow

```
sudo dpkg --configure -a
```

i see you have 4 package not upgraded

```
Reading state information... Done
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 1 reinstalled, 0 to remove and 4 not upgraded.
4 not fully installed or removed.
After this operation, 0 B of additional disk space will be used.
```

**Make sure** all package had been updated and upgraded, run

```
sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get upgrade && sudo apt-get autoremove
```

if the output log said

```
Errors were encountered while processing:  
python3.6-minimal  
python-minimal  
python3.6  
python3.6-dev
```

try to type `sudo apt-get install --fix-broken`

if you still have error encountered while processing that package, try to purge and remove all python and reinstall it again, follow

```
sudo apt-get purge python* && sudo apt-get autoclean && sudo apt-get install python*
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Okay, seems like I fixed it for 3.6 but not for 2.7 :(

Comment: what's about python2.7 ?

Comment: When I do `sudo apt-get install --fix-broken` I get the same error as before but for `python2.7` and `python2.7-minimal` respectively. I came accross this problem when I tried to install `pycharm`

Comment: @Humpawumpa I see you still have 16 apt not upgraded, make sure your apt updated/upgraded and run `sudo dpkg-reconfigure python2.7* `

Comment: When I do `upgrade` it says `0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded. 2 not fully installed or removed` and these two seem to be `python-minimal` and `python2.7-minimal`.
For the `reconfigure` command it tells me that `python2.7*` is an illegal package name, think it doesn't like the asterix.

Comment: @Humpawumpa remove them with type `sudo apt autoremove` and reinstall python2.7 package

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/83988/discussion-between-humpawumpa-and-abu-ahmed-al-khatiri).

Comment: Deleted the comment, and made a new question: [refer](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1374246/errors-were-encountered-while-processing-mercurial-common)

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem and was able to solve it with from [here](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/python3-defaults/+bug/1806399/comments/2) and then [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1324430/ubuntu-18-04-5-lts-python-3-can%C2%B4t-be-installed#comment2257352_1324430) . Non of the solutions with `apt install` or `apt purge` and then `apt autoremove` and ... worked for me unless I download them with `apt download` and then install them with `dpkg -i`.
This is what worked for me:

```
sudo apt-get download python3 python3.6 python3-minimal python3.6-minimal libpython3.6-minimal
sudo dpkg -i *python3*.deb
```

Here i got an error about `FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/usr/lib/python3.6/__phello__.foo.py'` which I was able to slove it with this:

```
sudo apt-get download libpython3.6-stdlib
sudo dpkg -i libpython3.6-stdlib*
```

After this everything that depended on that default (hard to install) `python3.6-minimal` worked. For example I could not install `ufw` before this but I could after.