# Fix packages with missing files

Tags: apt, 18.04, dpkg, data-corruption

Somehow two packages (that I don't want anymore) got corrupted after a file system check and are now missing files.

I installed and initialized `debsums` and when I run it it gives a load of missing files (and only missing files).

I tried these commands (found all over the place):

- `sudo apt upgrade`
- `sudo apt autoremove`
- `sudo apt install brscan4`
- `sudo apt remove brscan4`
- `sudo dpkg --configure -a`
- `sudo apt install --reinstall brscan4`
- `sudo apt install -f --reinstall brscan4`
- `sudo apt-get -f install` (without package name)
- `sudo dpkg --remove --force-remove-reinstreq brscan4`
- `sudo apt-get purge --remove brscan4`
- [added] `dpkg -P brscan4`

Notably, `dpkg --configure -a` seems to be recommended everywhere as if it's the final last-resort solution that's supposed to fix it.

They all give the exact same error:

> Removing brscan4 (0.4.4-3) ...
>   /var/lib/dpkg/info/brscan4.prerm: 3: /var/lib/dpkg/info/brscan4.prerm: /opt/brother/scanner/brscan4/setupSaneScan4: not found
>   dpkg: error processing package brscan4 (--remove):
>    installed brscan4 package pre-removal script subprocess returned error exit status 127

These commands do nothing to the corrupted packages:

- `sudo apt update`
- `sudo apt update --fix-missing`

How can I fix this short of [reinstalling Ubuntu from scratch](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1065556/broken-python-dependencies-after-trying-to-re-install)? (his final solution, see chat)

Comment: What do the commands  `dpkg -l brscan4`, `dpkg -L brscan4` say?

Comment: Try these commands in sequence, `sudo apt autoremove` followed by `sudo apt update`. Then, run  `sudo apt upgrade`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When prerm/postrm/postinst are failing, you need to remove the package with more low-level tools, as apt will stop on this error.

The first try is to use `dpkg -P brscan4` and when it works install brscan4 again using apt.

If still nothing works, edit the paths like `/var/lib/dpkg/info/brscan4.prerm` and insert `exit 0` as second line. The script will not run and not produce an error. After that, reinstalling will probably fix the errors and the re-installed script hopefully runs without problems.

Comment: `sudo dpkg -P brscan4`: same error again.

Comment: Then try the ``exit 0`` method. Check afterwards, if the scripts got replaced and if not remove the exit 0 line yourself and possibly reinstall the package (to run the script in an appropriate way, once all needed files are there again).

Comment: Thx, that did the trick.  I just had to execute the `apt remove` command and edit every `.prerm` and `.postinst` file it threw at me and empty it, until the remove works. Repeat for other packages.