# Cannot install python3-boto due to unmet dependencie which exists

Tags: apt

## Question

Please advise why python3-boto cannot be installed as in below.

```
$ sudo apt install -f python3-boto
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 python3-boto : Depends: python3-requests but it is not going to be installed
                Depends: python3:any (>= 3.3.2-2~)
                Depends: python3-six but it is not going to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

The python3-requests and python3-six are already installled.

```
$ sudo apt install -f python3-requests
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
python3-requests is already the newest version (2.18.4-2ubuntu0.1).
0 to upgrade, 0 to newly install, 0 to remove and 0 not to upgrade.


$ sudo apt install -f python3-six
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
python3-six is already the newest version (1.11.0-2).
0 to upgrade, 0 to newly install, 0 to remove and 0 not to upgrade.
```

Tried [Broken python dependencies after trying to re-install](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1065556/broken-python-dependencies-after-trying-to-re-install) but made no difference.

## Environment

64 bit DELL laptop.

```
NAME="Ubuntu"
VERSION="18.04.3 LTS (Bionic Beaver)"
ID=ubuntu
ID_LIKE=debian
PRETTY_NAME="Ubuntu 18.04.3 LTS"
VERSION_ID="18.04"
HOME_URL="https://www.ubuntu.com/"
SUPPORT_URL="https://help.ubuntu.com/"
BUG_REPORT_URL="https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/"
PRIVACY_POLICY_URL="https://www.ubuntu.com/legal/terms-and-policies/privacy-policy"
VERSION_CODENAME=bionic
UBUNTU_CODENAME=bionic
```

Comment: which Ubuntu version are you using? (This information is necessary)

Comment: @ThomasWard, thanks for the reminder. Updated.