# Ubuntu 18.04.5 LTS: Python 3 can´t be installed

Tags: 18.04, python3

I want to install python3 (on a ubuntu system I got some days ago from an employee who is not longer in our company) via

```
apt install python 3
```

but it gives me an error:

```
  Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/py_compile.py", line 186, in <module>
    sys.exit(main())
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/py_compile.py", line 178, in main
    compile(filename, doraise=True)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/py_compile.py", line 122, in compile
    source_bytes = loader.get_data(file)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 832, in get_data
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/usr/lib/python3.6/__phello__.foo.py'
dpkg: Fehler beim Bearbeiten des Paketes python3.6 (--configure):
 installed python3.6 package post-installation script subprocess returned error exit status 1
dpkg: Abhängigkeitsprobleme verhindern Konfiguration von python3:
 python3 hängt ab von python3.6 (>= 3.6.7-1~); aber:
  Paket python3.6 ist noch nicht konfiguriert.
 dpkg: Fehler beim Bearbeiten des Paketes python3 (--configure):
 Abhängigkeitsprobleme - verbleibt unkonfiguriert
```

Every "other" package (not related to python) can be installed and apt is working correctly. What could I do?

Comment: Can you try with this: `sudo apt-get install python3.6`?

Comment: yes, but it throws: ``` File "/usr/lib/python3.6/py_compile.py", line 186, in <module>
    sys.exit(main())
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/py_compile.py", line 178, in main
    compile(filename, doraise=True)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/py_compile.py", line 122, in compile
    source_bytes = loader.get_data(file)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 832, in get_data
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/usr/lib/python3.6/__phello__.foo.py' dpkg: ```

Comment: Fehler beim Bearbeiten des Paketes python3.6 (--configure):
 installed python3.6 package post-installation script subprocess returned error exit status 1

Comment: Check this [link](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1065556/broken-python-dependencies-after-trying-to-re-install)

Comment: File `/usr/lib/python3.6/__phello__.foo` is provided by package `libpython3.6-stdlib` - perhaps you need to re-install it?

Comment: that worked! thanks steeldriver! I was able to install python3.6 now! GREAT MAN! and of course thanks to singrium and mahesh, too :)

Comment: @steeldriver I spent HOURS of searching and that was it! although I could not install it with `apt` and had to download it with `apt download libpython3.6-stdlib` and install it manually with `dpkg -i libpython3.6-stdlib*`. THANK YOU!